# Why is the scroll event not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm using the scroll event in two different ways:

1)

```
$('#fullContainer').on('scroll', function () {

     console.log("-------------")
 })
```

This prints the log.

2) But when I use it like this,

```
$(document).on('scroll','#fullContainer', function () {

     console.log("-------------");
 });
```

It does not print the log. Why?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQs6p/1/)

Comment: This is because the scroll event does not bubble up the hierarchy [W3 Doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll)

Comment: so how I can use this scroll event with document

Comment: actually Problem is that I am only able to write this index.html .But I want to write in js file

Comment: But when I write on js file it not work ?

Comment: It is call in all pages.I need to call on particular div . $(document).on('scroll', function () {       console.log("-------------");  });

Comment: how to get id $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {   


    console.log("-------------"+e.target.attr('id')); 

});

Comment: @user1542984 you can't set it on DOCUMENT to get ID of scrolled container because event doesn't bubble

Answer (score 0):

This could be a workaround to kind of delegating onscroll event for specific element:

```
$(document).one('mouseenter', '#fullContainer', function () {
    $(this).on('scroll', function () {

        console.log("-------------", this.id)
    })
});
```

Comment: how to get id ..?$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {   


    console.log("-------------"+e.target.attr('id')); 

});

Comment: user answer is fine .But if I want to like that . how I will get id.please check fiddle ,I ma not able to get id http://jsfiddle.net/YQs6p/4/

Comment: console.log("-------------"+e.target.attr('id')); 
Answer should be fullContainer

Comment: @A.Wolff  while scrolling the it logs in console. but while scrolling the document, its throwing errors, can u please explain why?

Comment: id of div in which it is scroll

Comment: @user1542984 so what is not working with this jsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/YQs6p/3   Like said, if you bind scroll event to DOCUMENT, then there is no scroll event fired for specific container because scroll event doesn't bubble.

Comment: @TilwinJoy the error is relative to jquery mobile, not relevant to question here, see: http://jsfiddle.net/YQs6p/8/

Comment: second question ? instead  of mouse enter I need to use touch move on mobile device ?

Comment: Try using touchstart event instead